# Can a person be a guru for his own wife?

Tags: women, guru, initiation, upasana

Is it allowed for a person to be a guru for his own wife? Does any scripture disallows it?

Comment: Why not? Ramakrishna Paramahamsa and Lahiri Mahasaya were guru of their wife.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the Tantras it is *usually* not ok for the husband to initiate his wife. But if the husband is Siddha Mantra (mastered a Mantra) **then he can.**

The [Brihat TantrasArah](http://www.shivashakti.com/tantrasara.htm) quotes the following verses from the Rudra YAmala Tantram in this context:

> RudrayAmale:
>
> Na patnim dikshayed bhartA na pitA dikshayeth sutAm |
>  Na putrancha
> tathA bhrAtA brAtaram nacha dikshayet ||
>  **Siddha mantro yadi pati
> stadA patnim sa dikshayet |**
>  Shakti tvena varArohe na cha sA putrikA
> bhavet ||
>
> In Rudra YAmala Lord Shiva says to Goddess PArvati:
>
> A husband must not initiate his wife; a father his son or daughter; a
> brother a brother. **However, if the husband is Siddha Mantra, he
> can initiate his wife** but then he can not behave with her like a
> daughter (because for a Guru his disciples are like his children) like he does with his other disciples.

So, it is not totally disallowed. A Siddha Guru can initiate his wife but his behavior towards her should be like a husband and not like a father.

Now, if we talk about the Smritis (like Manu Smriti etc), then according to those texts, a wife is not qualified to be initiated (here initiation means the Vedic initiation). So, the question itself does not arise.

But Smritis say for a wife, his husband is her Guru and her stay in his house is the Gurukula VAsa and etc.

> Manu Smriti 2.67. The nuptial ceremony is stated to be the Vedic
> sacrament for women (and to be equal to the initiation), serving the
> husband (equivalent to) the residence in (the house of the) teacher,
> and the household duties (the same) as the (daily) worship of the
> sacred fire.

Comment: what about wife initiating husband into tantra

Comment: Thats not allowed i think

Comment: I have not seen any ref like that .. so probably not allowed ... @RakeshJoshi

Comment: @ParthaBanerjee That book we were talking abt was probably published by Viswabharati Univ Santiniketan and not by RK Mission Institute of culture ... and can u tell in all how many vols are there?

Comment: RMIC got the permission to publish it long ago

Comment: Oh but how many volumes it has in total? @ParthaBanerjee

Comment: Two volumes of around 600 pages each.Hard bound

Comment: Okay thx ... @ParthaBanerjee

Comment: U r welcme.....

Comment: @Rickross ISBN 978-81-87332-81-1 and 978-93-81325-3, priced Rs 300 each

Answer (score 1):

This answer is as per the Kāraṇāgama (कारणागम), one of the 28 Śaivāgamas.

- ##### For a Dwija-Women, especially the Brahmiṇa-lady, it is preferred that the husband is the "initiator" for his wife, and thus her Guru.

- ##### For the Non-dvija women, the husband is not preferred to be an initiator because a non-Brahmiṇa as a guru is said to be unfavorable.

Quoting from [Chapter 2](https://archive.org/details/karan-agama-by-r.-m.-prabhulinga-shastri-shaiva-bharati-varanasi/page/n51/mode/2up) (dvitīyaḥ paṭalaḥ): kriyāpādaḥ

> क्रियापादः
>  ॥ द्वितीयः पटलः ॥
>
> ब्राह्माणीनां हि दीक्षाया ग्रहणं भर्तृतो वरम् । भर्तर्यशक्ते
> ग्रहणमन्यतो वा विषिष्यते ॥ ५३ ॥
>
> > 53. **It is good for brahmiṇa-woman to be initiated by the husband. If husband
> >     is incapable, then it is good to be done by others.**
>
> अब्राह्मणीनां युज्येत भर्तृतो ग्रहणं नहि । अब्राह्माणस्य पत्युवा
> नोपदेष्टुत्वमिष्यते ॥ ५४ ॥
>
> > 54. **It is not good for a non-brahmiṇa woman to be initiated by her
> >     husband. Having been initiated by un-brahmiṇa husband is not honored.**
>
> पत्नया भर्तृगुरौ चैव भर्त्रा पत्नीगुरावपि । गुरुदृष्टिर्विधया
> स्यादन्यथा पततो धुवम् ॥ ५५ ॥
>
> > 55. Either a wife or a husband must keep reverence upon the husband - preacher or husband upon the wife - preacher respectively. If they
> >     don't do so respectively, they will be certainly deprived of that
> >     Vrat.
>
> English Translation by R. M. Prabhulinga Shastri