# Which scriptures tell that a husband-wife couple stays together for seven births?

Tags: marriage

It is a popular belief in people that the togetherness of a husband-wife couple is for seven births.
In which scripture(s) this thing is written?

Answer (score 6):

### The popular belief in people that the togetherness of husband-wife couple is for seven births - is a Misnomer.

As per the Kāraṇāgama (कारणागम), which is one of the 28 Śaivāgamas, the bond between a husband and wife is only for their present incarnation/birth and not everlasting', as popularly thought of or portrayed in the TV/cinemas.

This notion of 'couple staying together for seven births' might have crept as a corollary from the marriage-ritual involving the [Saptapadi](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11804/what-are-the-saptapadi-or-the-seven-promises-of-marriage) (सप्तपदी) rites (husband and wife taking seven steps) in a Marriage ceremony.

As I discuss in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/50614/17833) about the "women independence" & their eligibility to  get initiated, we have verse that also say '*couple relationship is only for their present birth*'.

> Chapter 2 (dvitīyaḥ paṭalaḥ): kriyāpādaḥ, Kāraṇāgama
>
> महादेव उवाच:
>
> > Bhagvān Shiva said -
>
> पतिपत्नीत्वसम्बन्धो न नित्यः कल्पितो हि सः ।
> नारीिनरत्वादिकमप्यैहजन्मिकमीरितम् ॥ ६२ ॥
>
> > 62. **Relation of wife and husband is not the ever lasting—thing. That is
> >     the thing of supposition. It is said that to be a woman or man is also of this incarnation only.**
>
> नैव स्त्री न पुमानेष नैव चायं नपुंसकः । 
> यद्यच्छरीमाधत्ते तेन तेन स
> लिप्यते ॥ ६३ ॥
>
> > 63. This soul (Atma) is neither a woman, a man nor an impotent one. It
> >     wears that and that body in which and which it dwells.
>
> नारीत्वमैहिकं वाऽपि भार्यात्वं कल्पितं तथा । निरुन्धतः कथं तन्व्याः
> पन्थानं मोक्षगामिनम् ॥ ६४ ॥
>
> > 64. **To be a woman is the subject of this incarnation. Like this, to be a wife is also.** How can these items of the subject (womanhood, entity
> >     of wife) prevent the path of salvation for her?

---

###### Exceptions are not the generalized rule:

There maybe be some examples like - Vasudeva & Devakī who have had multiple births as a couple, as one instance is elucidated in the [Chapter 3](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57167.html), Book 4 of the Devī Bhāgavata Purāṇa. Similar examples for other "divine-origin" couples may also be found in other scriptures too. However, it must be duly noted that these are examples of "divine-birth interventions", owing to a curse or boon to an 'exalted/divine-couple' and thus, as such, these may be treated as exceptions rather than a generalized rule for an average human.

Exceptions don't dictate the general rule, that is a well-known doctrine.

Comment: There are instances when same pati patni took incarnation again n again for whatever reasons. For example Vasudeva and Devakī, in their previous birth they were Sutapā and Pṛśni.  So we can't really deny this.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto - those must be treated as "exceptions" (IMO), and not the general trend. Exceptions in the scriptures cannot dictate and become the 'mundane rules' or generalized guidelines.  :)) . Plus, these are direct words of god Shiva himself. That ought to carry one of the Most Supreme weightage within Hinduism, I guess?! :))

Comment: "Relation of wife and husband is not the ever lasting—thing." doesn't deny that they may preserve relation for several births.

Comment: Thank you so much for awarding 50 points to Gryffindor  @SeverusSnape   :p

Comment: @hanugm Well, but did you read after, one janma is specified too